# Can I update a Conda environment with an interpreter

Tags: python, conda

I created an environment with the following command without specifiying an interpreter:

```
conda create --name myenv
```

However, I should have created it with this

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.6
```

Can I modify the environment to include the interpreter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can simply activate the environment (this is different depending on your version of conda and operating system)

**Since conda 4.4:**

```
conda activate myenv
```

**Before conda 4.4:**

Windows:

```
activate myenv
```

Linux/MacOS:

```
source activate myenv
```

**Installing...**

and then install any packages you need into it (conda treats python as a package)

```
conda install python=3.6
```

As mentioned in comments you can also install directly into the environment without activating:

```
conda install -n myenv python=3.6
```

Comment: No need to activate: `conda install -n myenv python=3.6`.

Comment: In addition, the more recent command is `conda activate myenv` and should be the same on all platforms (since conda 4.4)